# Exercise about fundamental group of mapping cone

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Let $X,Y$ be a path-connected space, $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous map and $C_f$ be a mapping cone(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_(topology)). If $π_1(Y) = 0$ then $π_1(C_f) = 0$.

The answer on the text book is as follows.

Let $U = Y \cup (X \times (\frac{1}{2},1]), V = X\times [0,1)$. $V$ is contractible. Apply Seifert–van Kampen theorem to $U$ and $V$ and get result.

I understand $π_1(U) = π_1(Y)*π_1(X)*π_1((\frac{1}{2},1]) = π_1(X), π_1(V) = π_1(X)$. However, I have no idea from here.

Comment: You actually forget the amalgamated relation in Seifert-Van Kampen Thm. If you take that into consideration, you'll see that everything in $\pi_1(X)$ gets quotient out.

Comment: Let $y_0=f(x_0)$ then, $$\frac{\pi_1(Y,y_0)}{f_*\pi_1(X,x_0)}\simeq \pi_1\big(C_f,[y_0]\big).$$